# How to overlay 2 videos with ffmpeg so that overlay starts before the main video?

Tags: ffmpeg

This command overlays the intro over the main clip and the main clip starts at the 11th second but the intro is not playing before that 11th second but only when the main video starts. I would like to have the intro play before the main clip and also overlay the main clip starting at the 11th second. I simplified the commad (the intro is made transparent so that main clip is actually visible when they overlap).

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i ovelay.mov -i main.mp4 -an -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[intro];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+11/TB[main_clip];[main_clip][intro]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" "out.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the tpad filter to add 11 seconds of black frames to the start of the main video.

`ffmpeg.exe -y -i ovelay.mov -i main.mp4 -an -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[intro];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,tpad=start_mode=add:start_duration=11:color=black[main_clip];[main_clip][intro]overlay=eof_action=pass[out]" -map "[out]" "out.mp4"`